# Simple encoding of category of sets and functions in Agda

Tags: agda, category-theory

This is a very basic question on Agda and Category Theory. I want to encode a category where objects are finite sets and arrows are functions between them. I'm using the [agda/agda-categories](https://github.com/agda/agda-categories) repo for `Category` definition. I'm having trouble with levels. Here's the current WIP code:

```
-- | Category Theory by Steve Awodey
--
-- Page 6. Book mentions injective functions, but just to clarify we
-- will confirm that non-injective functions work just as well.
--

open import Algebra
open import Function using (_∘_)
open import Algebra.Structures
open import Categories.Category
open import Level
open import Relation.Binary.Core
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

data FiniteSet (o : Level) : Set o where
  MkFiniteSet1 : FiniteSet o
  MkFiniteSet2 : FiniteSet o

record AnyFiniteSetFunc (ℓ : Level) : Set ℓ where
  constructor MkAnyFiniteSetFunc
  field
    func : (FiniteSet ℓ → FiniteSet ℓ)

noninjCat : {o ℓ e : Level} → Category o ℓ e
noninjCat {o} {ℓ} {e} =
  record
    { Obj = FiniteSet o
    ; _⇒_ = λ _ _ → AnyFiniteSetFunc ℓ
    ; _≈_ = λ x₂ x₁ → {!(_≡_) x₁ x₂!}
    ; id = MkAnyFiniteSetFunc (\(el : FiniteSet ℓ) → el)
    ; _∘_ = λ f1 f2 →
            MkAnyFiniteSetFunc
              ( AnyFiniteSetFunc.func f1
              ∘ AnyFiniteSetFunc.func f2
              )
    ; assoc = λ {A} {B} {C} {D} {f} {g} {h} → {!!}
    ; identityˡ = {!!}
    ; identityʳ = {!!}
    ; equiv = {!!}
    ; ∘-resp-≈ = {!!}
    }
```

The Goal/Have mismatch I have in hole `0` is this one:

```
Goal: Set e
Have: Set ℓ
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
x₁ : AnyFiniteSetFunc ℓ
x₂ : AnyFiniteSetFunc ℓ
B  : FiniteSet o  (not in scope)
A  : FiniteSet o  (not in scope)
e  : Level
ℓ  : Level
o  : Level
```

There must be something I'm not doing right with levels there, or maybe a complete mis-conception of how the equality should be encoded.

Repo with my WIP code is here: https://github.com/k-bx/category-theory-exercises/blob/master/agda/ex02_noninjective_functions.agda

Comment: You notion of arrows completely ignores the source and target types. It's probably wrong.

Comment: @gallais what's wrong with ignoring them? All arrows are in the same constant types in this example, sometimes it's even more trivial, like when I enclosed a monoid as category https://k-bx.github.io/articles/boring-monoid-category.html Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Actually, sorry, I see your point. AnyFiniteSetFunc might need an additional parameterization, will think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've just realized the answer might be that we want to state that levels `ℓ` and `e` are equal for this category, so this worked:

```
noninjCat : {o ℓ : Level} → Category o ℓ ℓ
noninjCat {o} {ℓ} =
  record
    { Obj = FiniteSet o
    ; _⇒_ = λ _ _ → AnyFiniteSetFunc ℓ
    ; _≈_ = λ {A} {B} x₂ x₁ → x₁ ≡ x₂
    ; id = MkAnyFiniteSetFunc (\(el : FiniteSet ℓ) → el)
    ; _∘_ = λ f1 f2 →
            MkAnyFiniteSetFunc
              ( AnyFiniteSetFunc.func f1
              ∘ AnyFiniteSetFunc.func f2
              )
    ; assoc = λ {A} {B} {C} {D} {f} {g} {h} → {!!}
    ; identityˡ = {!!}
    ; identityʳ = {!!}
    ; equiv = {!!}
    ; ∘-resp-≈ = {!!}
    }
```